# Scala recursive function else if returning Unit

Tags: scala, tail-recursion

Noob Scala question:

I have the following code extract:

```
@tailrec
def buildObjectFromFile(dataList: List[String], fileObject: IncomingFile): IncomingFile = {
  dataList match {
    case Nil => fileObject

    case data :: list =>
      val recordIdentifier = data.substring(0, 2)

      if (recordIdentifier.equals("00")) {
        val fileHeader = new fFileHeader(
            ...
        )

        buildObjectFromFile(list, new IncomingFile(fileHeader, fileObject.accountsList, fileObject.fileTrailer))
      } else if (recordIdentifier.equals("01")) {
        val accountHeader = new AccountHeader(
          ...
        )

        fileObject.accountsList += new Account(data.substring(12, 22), accountHeader, null, null, null)

        buildObjectFromFile(list, new IncomingFile(fileObject.fileHeader, fileObject.accountsList, fileObject.fileTrailer))
      } else if (recordIdentifier.equals("99")) {  // <--- Problematic
        val fileTrailer = new FileTrailer(
          ...
        )

        buildObjectFromFile(list, new IncomingFile(fileObject.fileHeader, fileObject.accountsList, fileTrailer))
      }
  }
}
```

This code doesn't compile because the compiler complains that the last `else if` block returns a `Unit`, while it is required to return an `IncomingFile` type. I don't understand why only the last `if` statement is problematic.

Comment: Is the return type from `buildObjectFromFile` correct, i.e. `IncomingFile`? Also, you should probably add an `else` block otherwise the retrun value will be `AnyVal`.

Comment: I'd make the `dataList` test an `if`...`else` and then do the pattern `match` on `data.substring(0, 2)`. The logic would be easier to read/follow and the result type is consistent even if you don't have a default (i.e. final `else`).

Comment: First of all add else block.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can fix by implementing else for whole if-else-if expression. Now you don't have it so the whole block is has Unit type